# Java in Google App Engine: alternative for fileoutputstream

Tags: java, google-app-engine, fileoutputstream

So I have a Java project that gets a content through an API request. Then, it saves the content in a file, which it uploads using another API. Now I want to use the Google App Engine, which doesn't support the fileoutputstream. I know you can use the datastore, but it can't really save a file.

Is there an alternative for this problem?

Comment: use Google Cloud Storage for files

Comment: I tried, following the tutorial on google docs, It fails to link the app to the Cloud Storage

Comment: I believe it's better to ask question about this "fail" then